# How to pass the result of a keyword to a roboframework template?

Tags: robotframework

I am running a templated test where I would like to pass the current date or None as the third parameter to the template.

```
Completeness
[Documentation]  All the fields must be set or the it would fail
[Tags]  new-antifraud
[Template]  When we update the record with id ${id} outcome ${outcome} datetime ${update_datetime} the result should be ${result}

Id1 Accept '${Get Current Date  UTC}' John  Ok
Id2 None '${Run Keyword  Get Current Date  UTC}'  Mark  Error
None Accept  '${Run Keyword  Get Current Date  UTC}' Susan  Error
```

Is there a right syntax which allows to obtain this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, no, robot has no syntax to allowing calling a keyword and using the result as an argument to another keyword. However, you could certainly write your template keyword to require that you pass in a keyword as a parameter, and the template keyword can run the keyword for you.

There is an open issue in the robot framework issue tracker for inline keyword evaluation: [issue #3187](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/3187)

Comment: So the question is the following, can you set variables to pass to test template inside the test or should you use other strategies? which are the most appropriate strategies?

Comment: @Edmondo1984: you could set a variable in test setup.